# Why the output is 36 and not 24?

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int f(int a, int b) {
    int a1 = a, b1 = b;

    while (a1 != b1)
        if (a1 < b1) a1 += a;
        else b1 += b;

    return a1;
}

int main() {
    printf("%d\n", f(12, 18));
    return 0;
}
```

Hi, I don't understand why the result is 36, can someone explain me ?

Comment: Why do you assume it should be 24? And please indent the code.

Comment: did you step  through the code in a debugger, or at least add some print statements.

Comment: I don't understand either. Probably I would understand it if the code were properly indented.

Comment: What do you mean by indented ?

Comment: f(12,18) -> (24,18) -> (24,36) -> (36,36) -> return

Comment: Some one just indented your code. Look at it now and you'ill understand what it means.

Comment: Do you know what the code is supposed to calculate? (Where does it come from?) It's an implementation of this algorithm for 2 values: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple#Using_a_simple_algorithm

Comment: Time to set a breakpoint, and step through the code with a debugger, watching the variables change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's step it through:

```
f(12, 18) -> a = 12, b = 18
int a1 = a, b1 = b; -> a1 = 12, b1 = 18
while (a1 != b1) -> not equal -> do the loop
if (a1 < b1) a1 += a; -> a1 = 24
while (a1 != b1) -> not equal -> do the loop
if (a1 < b1) ... else b1 += b; -> b1 = 36
while (a1 != b1) -> not equal -> do the loop
if (a1 < b1) a1 += a; -> a1 = 36
while (a1 != b1) -> equal -> end the loop
return a1 -> return 36
```

Comment: Oh okay, so we have to do the loop until the condition is over ?

Comment: @Fran98038 Of course. That's the very nature of a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

After the first iteration of the while loop `a1` is equal to 24 due to this statement

```
if (a1 < b1) a1 += a;
```

So the condition of the loop

```
while (a1 != b1)
```

is true. `a1` is equal to `24`, `b1` is equal to `18`. `a1` is not equal to `b1`.

Now in the second iteration `b1` is less than `a1` so the else statement

```
else b1 += b;
```

is executed.

Now `b1` is equal to 36.

In the third iteration `a1` again is less than `b1` so `a1` becomes equal to `36` as `b1` due to executing the statement

```
if (a1 < b1) a1 += a;
```

So the loop stops. And the function returns `36`.